# What kind of creature is a "Foliot"?

Tags: mythology, folklore, worm-ouroboros

In the high fantasy novel *The Worm Ouroboros* by E. R. Eddison one of [the many kingdoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Worm_Ouroboros#The_kingdoms_of_Mercury) are *the Foliot Islands*. The leader of these people is the Red Foliot.

What kind of creature is a *foliot*? From what I have been able to research, they are some sort of genii or protector spirit, but I haven't been able to learn much about these creatures.

I know that countries have quite "childish" names in *The Worm Ouroboros*, since Eddison composed this work with some characters and names he created when he was 9 years old, and in spite of the countries being named "Demonland", "Goblinland" or "Witchland" its inhabitants are not really demons, traditional goblins, etc. So, more that what they are in Edisson's work I what to know what is the creature that inspired this race or kingdom in *The Worm Ouroboros*.

Comment: Foliots are a type of rather weak demon in Stroud's Bartimaeus Sequence, though I've not seen the word used elsewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In "[The Anatomy of Melancholy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Anatomy_of_Melancholy)" by Robert Burton (written in 1621), foliots are described as being a sort of poltergeist.

> Another sort of these there are, which frequent forlorn houses, which
>   the Italians call foliots, most part innoxious, Cardan holds: ***'They
>   will make strange noises in the night, howl sometimes pitifully, and
>   then laugh again, cause great flame and sudden lights, fling stones,
>   rattle chains, shave men, open doors and shut them, fling down
>   platters, stools, chests, sometimes appear in the likeness of hares,
>   crows, black dogs, etc.,'*** of which read Pet. Thyraeus the Jesuit, in
>   his tract de locis infestis, part. 1, cap. 1 et cap. 4, **who will have
>   them to be devils or the souls of damned men that seek revenge, or
>   else souls out of purgatory that seek ease**; for such examples peruse
>   Sigismundus Scheretzius, lib. de spectris, part. 1, cap. 1, which he
>   saith he took out of Luther most part; there be many instances.
>   Plinius Secundus remembers such a house at Athens, which Athenodorus
>   the philosopher hired, which no man durst inhabit for fear of devils.
>   Austin, de Civ. Dei, lib. 22, cap. 8, relates as much of Hesperius the
>   tribune's house at Zubeda, near their city of Hippo, vexed with evil
>   spirits, to his great hindrance [and to the great distress of his animals and slaves].